# OpenCV: Unable to correctly pass data to a function

Tags: c++, opencv

Compiling on Windows with MSVS2010

In the following code I have tried to use Line iterator and then after extracting the pixel values along the line, I am trying to pass the extracted data to a function `foo()`:

The image is a single channel 16 bit png.

```
int foo(unsigned short int *values,  unsigned int nSamples)
{
    cout<<"address in PlotMeNow"<<endl;
    cout<<&values[0]<<endl; 
    cout<<"values in PlotMeNow"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<values[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;  
}

unsigned short int * IterateLine(Mat image)
{
    LineIterator it(image, Point(1,1), Point(5,5), 8);
    vector<ushort> buf;

    for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, it++){
        buf.push_back(image.at<ushort>(it.pos()));
    }

    std::vector<ushort> data(5);
    data=buf; 

    cout<<"the  address in the iterateLine() is"<<endl; 
    cout<<&data[0]<<endl; 

    cout<<"values in IterateLine"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<data[i]<<endl;
    }
     return &data[0]; 
}

int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("sir.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    unsigned short int * x ; 
    //Iterate through the line  
    x =  IterateLine(img); 

    int n=5; 
    foo(&x[0], n);

    cout<<"The address in main() is"<<endl; 
    cout<<x<<endl; 
    cout<<"values in main are"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){  
        cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    }     
    getch();
    return 0 ; 
}
```

**The output of the program is:**

```
the address in the iterateLine() is
001195D8
values in IterateLine
40092
39321
39578
46003
46774
address in foo()
001195D8
values in foo()
56797
56797
56797
56797
56797
The address in main() is
001195D8
values in main() are
56797
56797
56797
56797
56797
```

As can be seen the values `foo()` and `main()` are wrong. It should be same as that reported by `IterateLine()`.  Since address are passed correctly (see in the output ) so using pointers I should get same data from any function.  But its not happening.

Why is this happening and how do I correctly pass data to `foo()`?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to local data in from `IterateLine`. That is undefined behaviour. You should fix that first.

Comment: @juanchopanza But when addresses are same , why data would be different?

Comment: Because something else put other data there, because it can?

Comment: @juanchopanza The value at address 001195D8 and 001195D8+1 , cannot be different for different functions. Am I wrong?

Comment: Who cares? You have undefined behaviour. That is a bug. Fix it first.

Comment: IterateLine(const Mat & image, vector<ushort> & linePixels) // pass it by reference, instead of returning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void IterateLine( const Mat& image, vector<ushort>& linePixels, Point p1, Point p2 )
{
    LineIterator it(image, p1,p2, 8);

    for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, it++){
        linePixels.push_back(image.at<ushort>(it.pos()));
    }
}

int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("sir.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);

    vector<ushort> linePixels;        // initially empty
    IterateLine( img, linePixels, Point(1,1), Point(5,5) );  

    foo( &linePixels[0], linePixels.size() );

    return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have to pass a third parameter for Point(X1,X2), Point(Y1,Y2). SO there would be three arguments to my function.